# MySQL: Updating an item only if certain conditions are met

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Does anyone know how to update a row only if one of it's column does not equal to the same coloumn in another row in the table?

Let me explain. Consider this table. It stores some bookings and the admin can decide which one to approve.

```
Booking |  Time | Approved
   0    |  5:00 |   NO
   1    |  5:00 |   NO
   2    |  6:00 |   YES
   3    |  6:00 |   NO
```

The booking requests can overlap, such is the case with Booking 0 and 1. The admin can decide either to approve 0, or 1.

But approved bookings cannot overlap. For example, Since booking 2 is already approved for 6:00, booking 3 cannot be approved. Unless the admin decides to disapparove booking 2 first.

How would I write a query for this to check that no collision will happen? I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
 UPDATE requests
 SET Approved = 'YES'
 WHERE Booking = 3
 AND NOT EXISTS (
    (SELECT Time 
    FROM requests
    WHERE Booking = 3)
    = 
    (SELECT Time
    From requests
    WHERE Booking != 3)
 );
```

But that doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

As a side note. My actual problem is a little more complicated. The table looks more like

```
Booking |  Start Time | End Time |Approved
   0    |  5:00       |   6:00   | NO
   1    |  5:00       |   7:00   | NO
   2    |  6:00       |   8:00   | YES
   3    |  6:00       |   9:00   | NO
```

And I'm trying to prevent overlapping bookings. But I'm sure if I got the syntax right for the simple version of the problem, then i'll be able to figure out the complex version too.

Comment: There's no `id` column in your table. Is that supposed to be `booking`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, booking. will correct now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using `NOT EXISTS` correctly. Its argument should be a single subquery, not an expression comparing two subqueries. In your case, the condition in the subquery is that it's the same time, but a different ID than the one you're updating, and the other one is already approved.

```
UPDATE request AS r1
SET approved = 'YES'
WHERE r1.id = 3
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM request AS r2
    WHERE r2.time = r1.time AND r2.id != r1.id AND r2.approved = 'YES'
)
```

To get around the error, use the `LEFT JOIN / NULL` pattern.

```
UPDATE request AS r1
LEFT JOIN request AS r2 ON r2.time = r1.time AND r2.id != r1.id AND r2.approved = 'YES'
SET r1.approved = 'YES'
WHERE r1.id = 3 AND r2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Isn't mysql the database where you can't specify the target table for an update in a from clause?

Comment: This worked for me, except as @Solarflare said. You can't specify the target table for an update in a from clause. So I changed it to "...NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM request) AS r2 WHERE ...." And it works properly.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the correct way to get around that error.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `exists` incorrectly. But in mysql, you cannot specify the table you want to update in a from clause, so you couldn't use it anyway.

But you can use a `join`. So for your simple version that would be:

```
update requests r1
left join requests r2
on r1.id <> r2.id and r1.time = r2.time and r2.Approved = 'YES'
set r1.Approved = 'YES'
where r1.id = 3 
and r2.id is null;
```

You can of course use a join for your more complicated version too. Since you want to try it yourself, I'll add the solution to that tomorrow (or if you ask for it).

Or you can do a select first. There you could use `exists`. Then you would be able to show an error message to the user. Since this update will just do nothing if there would already be an entry.

```
select count(*) 
from requests r1
where r1.id = 3
and not exists 
  (select * from requests r2
   where r1.id <> r2.id and r1.time = r2.time and r2.Approved = 'YES'
  );
```

Comment: What is 'count' in the second example?

Comment: @Synia `count(*)` will return the number of rows that are selected. In this case, it will be 1 if you can update the row, and 0 if either id=3 doesn't exists or if another row has `approved = yes` for that time. So kind of a boolean flag if it is allowed to update the row. You could check beforehand if such a row exists, to be able to return e.g. an error message. You should still use the safe `update`-version, since it is possible that someone else changed the value in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I am selecting the time from the ID to be approved and then checking if that time is already present in the table with an approved='YES'
if not present, update.

```
update request
set
approved = 'YES'
where not exists(select 'yes' from request where time = 
(select time from request where id=1) and approved='YES')
```